# Parsing and using the HTTP Range header with Spring

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, range, http-range

I'm writing a Spring controller that needs to accept the `Range` header, use the values there to request some data using a 3rd-party library, then return the result.

The Spring [`HttpRange`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpRange.html) class looks promising, specifically the [`parseRanges`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpRange.html#parseRanges-java.lang.String-) function, which says:

> Parse the given, comma-separated string into a list of `HttpRange` objects.
>
> This method can be used to parse an [sic] Range header.

However, this class doesn't provide any interface to extract the parsed values without knowing the "the total length of a representation".

Given I am handling a request which I'll forward to another API, I don't know the total length.

Is there a standard Spring way to inspect the Range header and extract the values without knowing the length? I want to avoid writing a custom parser if possible.

Comment: Are you able to pass the header as-is? It *sounds* like that may be enough. Otherwise: "inspect the Range header and extract the values" -- what are you looking for here in the case of open-ended ranges? How are you looking to transform them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
HttpHeaders rangeHeaders = new ServletServerHttpRequest(httpRequest).getHeaders();
List<HttpRange> ranges = rangeHeaders.getRange();
```

Refer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#getRange()